# Scraping iframe table with R/rvest

Tags: html, r, iframe, web-scraping, rvest

I know there are some similar questions on this issue, but they did not help at all. I have limited knowledge about HTML.

I am trying to scrape this website:

https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/enetconsulta/frmGerenciaPaginaFRE.aspx?CodigoTipoInstituicao=1&NumeroSequencialDocumento=68338

I am interested in the items 13/13.2 selected with the combo boxes (Remuneração dos administradores / Remuneração total por órgão - this is portuguese).  After you select the items, you see an iframe with a table. I want to scrape the info on this table.

At first I tried:

```
"https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/enetconsulta/frmGerenciaPaginaFRE.aspx?
CodigoTipoInstituicao=1&NumeroSequencialDocumento=68338" %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("iframe") %>%
  extract(1)
```

Which gives:

```
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <iframe id="ctl00_cphPopUp_iFrameFormulariosFilho" width="100%" 
style="height: 525px; overflow ...
```

However, I couldn't get past through it, no Xpath seem to work from this point.

Any help?

Thanks a lot.